# jQuery Slider to stretch full Width Height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement Nerve slider where i want to stretch across the width of the browser and the height. I have even specified a fixed width for the Div still the Plugin seems to re-size it.

Any idea how i can force the height and the width to the full size of the temporary background image.

http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/

```css
.homeSlider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 990px;
    position: absolute;
}
.homeSlider > #slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 990px !important;
    background-image:100%;
}
```

**Edit**

Changing the Height and width to 100% did the job. When i Resize the browser i get a white space in that section. Any way i can make the slider fit in that section but the height should not be resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the start of the default settings in the non-minified version of the plugin:

```
$.fn.startslider = function (userOptions) {
    var options = $.extend({
        sliderWidth: "1200px",
        sliderHeight: "500px",
```

When you initialise the slider on your page, you need to override these values.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Michael, you can do:

```
    sliderWidth: $(window).width() +"px",
    sliderHeight: $(window).height()+"px"
```

Comment: the window depends on the browser size :(

Comment: Try combining this with `sliderWidth: $(window).width() +"px"` and `sliderHeight:"990px"`

Comment: thanks it worked. i used 100% and it seem to work. when i resize the browser there seem to be white space below the slider. any idea how i can address this

Comment: Because it's scaling the image at the correct aspect ratio, otherwise it would look weird if you compress a widescreen image into a fullscreen one.

Comment: @NickR the sldier has an option to crop and strech. so any idea how i can make sure it stays that height?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option when using the Nerve slider to set the slider to fullscreen.

```
$.fn.nerveSlider = function(userOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({
            sliderWidth: "1200px",
            sliderHeight: "500px",
            sliderHeightAdaptable: false,
            sliderFullscreen: false,
```

Just set this line to true:

```
sliderFullscreen: true,
```

Should do the trick.